# Conversion of bool type to int type error when trying to multiply with bool tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm doing an ML practice project using tensorflow to create a model. I am stuck at a problem where i have to create a filter_mask (bool) and then multiply it to data but i'm getting the following error or running.

> Tensor conversion requested dtype bool for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("mul_2:0", shape=(19, 19, 5, 80), dtype=float32)'

I'm not very familiar with tensorflow, i know that normally you can just multiply boolean values with integers and they act like 1 and 0. Is it different with tensorflow? How do I get past the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I mean a simple fix is just to cast your boolean array to floats and do the multiplication:

tensor = tf.cast(tensor, tf.float32)

Answer (score 0):

tf.math.greater return True or False value

```
print( tf.where(tf.math.greater( np.asarray(y1, dtype=np.float32), np.asarray(previous_cell, dtype=np.float32)), [1.0], [0.0]).numpy() )
```